# NgRx effect unit tests get Jasmine spy call counts mixed up

Tags: angular, jasmine, ngrx

I have an NgRx effects where I want to unit test a success and also a fail scenario. In the fail, I originally had an issue where if the `catch` was executed, it would kill the effect observable (same problem as explained, with solution [here](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/646)

I am using version 12.2.0 of NgRx.

So, in the fail scenario, I wanted to make sure a second call to the service within the effect would also work.

When I run this test in isolation it works fine. However, when I then added another test to test the success (calling the same API), when I run both, SOMETIMES (not all the time) the call count via the `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` on the Jasmine spy would now show the count from both tests, instead of just the one.

[image]

Seems to be quite random (like some sort of race condition).

I tried using `addEditedDataSpy.calls.reset()` but does not seem to help.

Here is the test code:

```
        const actions$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
        ...

        describe('addEditedData', () => {
            it('Should emit dataEditedDataSuccess and serverDataUpdated on addEditedData', done => {
                // Assemble
                const successPromise = new Promise<NoDataResult>((resolve) => { resolve({} as NoDataResult); });
                const addEditedDataSpy = spyOn(serverAPI, 'addEditedData').and.returnValue(successPromise);
                addEditedDataSpy.calls.reset();
                const data: Partial<EditedData> = {};

                // We have 2 actions expected, so we need to count
                let actionCount = 0;
                subs.sink = sut.dataEditedData$.subscribe(action => {
                    actionCount++;
                    // Asserts
                    const expectedOutcome = actionCount === 1
                        ? myActions.dataEditedDataSuccess()
                        : appActions.serverDataUpdated();

                    expect(action.type).toEqual(expectedOutcome.type);

                    if (actionCount === 2) {
                        done();
                    }
                });

                // Act
                actions$.next(myActions.dataEdited(data as EditedData));
            });

            it('Should emit dataEditedDataFail when addEditedData returns a promise reject (http error)', done => {
                // Assemble
                const errorPromise = new Promise<NoDataResult>((_, reject) => { reject(httpError); });
                const addEditedDataSpy = spyOn(serverAPI, 'addEditedData').and.returnValue(errorPromise);
                addEditedDataSpy.calls.reset();
                const data: Partial<EditedData> = {};
                let secondCall = false;
                subs.sink = sut.dataEditedData$.subscribe(action => {
                    // wait for second call so we can count the calls to dataEdited
                    if (!secondCall) {
                        return;
                    }

                    // Asserts
                    const expectedOutcome = myActions.dataEditedDataFail(httpError);
                    expect(action.type).toEqual(expectedOutcome.type);
                    expect(addEditedDataSpy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
                    done();
                });

                // Act
                actions$.next(myActions.dataEdited(data as EditedData));

                // Call again, just to show the effects observable has not been killed due to the error
                // (which can happen if exception is in the wrong place)
                secondCall = true;
                actions$.next(myActions.dataEdited(data as EditedData));
            });
        });
```

Note I also unsubscribe from the effects in the `beforeEach`, as I thought perhaps each tests subscriptions were the problem (but didn't really help)

[image]

What could be wrong here?

### Update 1

Here is the effect code. The only slightly unusual thing about it is I return 2 actions on success (which I am led to believe is OK)

```
public dataEditedData$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
            ofType(myActions.dataEdited),
            tap(_ => this.logger.info('dataEdited')),
            switchMap(action => from(this.serverAPI.addEditedData(action.data)).pipe(
                    switchMap(results =>
                        results.errors
                            ? [myActions.dataEditedDataFail(results.errors)]
                            : [myActions.dataEditedDataSuccess(), appActions.serverDataUpdated()]
                    ),
                    catchError(error => of(myActions.dataEditedDataFail(error)))
            ))));
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a complete answer but I think it would be good if you show the code of your `effect` as well.

I remember dealing with something similar to this but it was a `BehaviorSubject` subscription in two different tests and the subscriptions would leak. Jasmine runs the test in random order and I am thinking when both tests pass, test 1 came after test 2 and when one fails but the other passes, test 2 came after test 1.

It is strange how the `unsubscribing` didn't do the trick for you but try this in both tests to ensure the subscriptions get removed:

```
sut.dataEditedData$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe(....
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I tried that (have actually done that in the past when had similar problems unit testing Effect), but did not seem to help. Using breakpoints I can see the calls within the subscribes all seem to be behaving correctly - it is just the `toHaveBeenCalledTimes` that seems to be be being reset. Also added the effect under UPDATE1